# Spark SparkOutOfMemoryError despite having each task memory greater than input

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using 10 r4.8xlarge with 32 codes and 244 GB memory and 100GB SSD my input is 100 22GB txt files.

Below is my executor parameters

```
 --num-executors 59  --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 37g
```

I put executor-cores 5 because it seems like people recommend default to 5, and num-executors is `floor(32/5) * 10 - 1` executor-memory  is `(244 / floor(32/5)) (1 - 0.07)` as recommended in this tuning [tutorial](https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/)

Using the above configuration I am getting

```
org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: error while calling spill() on 
org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter@5eced6cb : No space left on device
```

Which correspond to this code

```
    return spark.sparkContext
    .textFile(myInputDir)
    .repartition(15800) // experimentally tested to be a good partition base on 1 file, 1 file the best repartition is 3000
```

Since each task get 37GB and that is more than 22GB, I am a bit confuse on how spark can reach `SparkOutOfMemoryError` as its just simply reading it and repartitioning it to other nodes.

Can someone point me a direction?

Comment: client or cluster modes? Master may not execute those executors .

Answer (score 0):

Shuffling always involves disk writes unless you use some in-memory layer (e.g. apache ignite)
Your error clearly states `No space left on device`, consider increasing disk capacity.

Comment: I added disk so that there is more than enough disk to spill shuffle, but is still having the same problem, is there some config that allocate disk like memory with executor-memory ?

Answer (score 0):

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/spark-job-failure-with-no-space-left-on-device/td-p/197465.

This can be the issue.Spark keeps intermediate files in /tmp, where it likely ran out of space. You can either adjust spark.local.dir or set this at submission time, to a different directory with more space. Try the same job while adding in this during spark-submit; --conf "spark.local.dir=/directory/with/space"